# Installation errors modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed my nodejs in C:/Program Files/nodejs

I have my nodejs project in C:/node

Whenever I want to install any modules( npm install underscore ) or ( npm install express)  I come across many errors, don't know why.

```
Error here: 
C:\>cd node

C:\node>npm install underscore
npm ERR! Error: Invalid name: "node- A to do app"
npm ERR!     at ensureValidName (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_m
odules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:302:15
)
npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixNameField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node
_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\
lib\fixer.js:206:5)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\re ad-packa
ge-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:29:38
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at normalize (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:28:15)
npm ERR!     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rea
d-package-json\read-json.js:328:33)
npm ERR!     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read
-package-json\read-json.js:126:33)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-packa
ge-json\read-json.js:302:48
npm ERR!     at fs.js:207:20
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.Req.done (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_
modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:144:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "underscore"
npm ERR! cwd C:\node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\node\npm-debug.log 
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The description you are using in your `package.json` is invalid.  You cannot use whitespace in the name and it is suggested that you only use lowercase characters.  Change your `package.json` to something like:

```
{
  "name": "mytodoapp",
  ...other package.json stuff you need...
}
```

Additionally, from the [NPM docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html):

> The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line, and a folder name. Any name with non-url-safe characters will be rejected. Also, it can't start with a dot or an underscore.

As a final comment, if you accidentally give your project the same name in `package.json` as another module you want to install, you will get errors about installing the module as a dependency of itself.  (So, don't name your project `express` for example...)  :)